# How to add newlines while writing to file using java?

Tags: java, file-io

```
    String filepath=jTextField1.getText();
    FileReader fr;
    try {            
        fr = new FileReader("C:\something.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String sf="";
        while((br.readLine())!=null){
            sf=sf+br.readLine()+"\n";               
        }
        jTextArea1.setText(sf);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DesktopApplication1View.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The output file contain read character write in single line the whole length. How to get file with newlines?

Comment: People would be more inclined to help you if you would Accept your previous questions.

Comment: as a best practice, use StringBuilder/StringBuffer insteead of appending to String.

Comment: That's not a file. There's no output file in that code.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code you are READING a file and then outputting the text to what looks like a swing text component.  I don't see where it is being declared so I can't say for sure what kind of component it is.  You need to set your Text component to be multiline.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `"\n"`, use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to ensure that you use the right line separator for your operating system.

As Manoj suggested, use `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating a `String`.

And, as maple_shaft already suggested, you need to set your Swing `Text` component to accept a multi-line string.